# How to set "CheckBoxes" to checked from treeview using javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-template

I'm using kendo mvvm frameworks. I would like to check certain checkbox with an array contain the checkbox value. 
Example

```
var checkboxValue=["a","c"]

[x]a
[ ]b
[x]c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var values = ["A", "C"];

var setTreeViewValues = function(values) {
    var tv = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

    tv.dataItems().forEach(function(dataItem) {
        if (values.indexOf(dataItem.text) > -1) {
            dataItem.set("checked", true);
        }
    });
};

setTreeViewValues(values);
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AGOnI)

It will check the node if the array contains its text. You better call this method on `dataBound` event if your treeView get its data from an async request.

Comment: I had change the datasource format then it won't work for me

Comment: @AustinHoh have you changed the condition inside the loop with your dataSource's correct property here: `values.indexOf(dataItem.text) > -1` ?